# Is it possible to add "Tags" or informational metadata to objects (Groups, Applications, IdPs, etc) in Okta

Tags: okta, okta-api

For reporting and automation purposes I would like to be able to add custom meta data or "tags" to various objects in Okta. Specifically Applications, IdPs, Groups, and Resource Sets.  I am NOT talking about SAML or custom profile metadata regarding apps/idps.  I mean strictly custom tagging or metadata in Okta so that we can more easily classify/report/and automate certain things.

I do not see a way to to it, either via Admin UI OR the API.  It does seem a little lacking to me that this is not part of a SAAS as mature as Okta, especially considering the hierarchical nature of the resource sets, groups, applications, users and so  on.

I don't need to actually *see* the tags visually in the Admin UI if they can somehow be done via API, but I don't see any way.

Can this be done or is there a workaround that someone has successfully employed to accomplish this?

By workaround I mean within Okta and not some completely external mapping database, which would make using those tags via built in reporting, for instance,  pretty much impossible.

I examined the Admin documentation as well as the API documentation and saw nothing that could be used or populated efficiently to support this need.